# Valor maximo de input

Tags: html, html5, input

Minha duvida é a seguinte, gostaria de saber qual é o máximo de caracteres que uma tag input text suporta, agradeço desde já pela atenção.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não encontrei algo que fale sobre o *máximo de caracteres* em um `input[type='text']` no site [HTML LS — Last Updated 8 July 2019](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html), até o momento o que eu encontrei foi:

[MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#maxlength) diz:

> Attr: **maxlength**
>   The maximum number of characters (as UTF-16 code units) the user can enter into the text input. This must be an integer value 0 or higher. **If no maxlength is specified, or an invalid value is specified, the text input has no maximum length.** This value must also be greater than or equal to the value of minlength.

Que traduzido seria algo como:
Se o atributo **maxlength** não esta definido ou tem um valor invalido o input text não tem tamanho máximo.

Já o [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp) diz:

> Attr: **maxlength**
>   The maximum number of characters allowed in the  element. **Default value is 524288**

ou seja, diz que o valor default do atributo **maxlength** é **524288**.

Olhando essas informações, não dá para garantir que o `input['text']` é ilimitado e nem que o máximo é 524288, eu usaria como base o valor que o W3Schools diz ser o padrão.

---

*[Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/396220/valor-maximo-de-input#comment778891_396223): “Apenas comentando, era esperado que as especificações não definissem isso porque é uma limitação de implementação, não de especificação. O navegador (ou qualquer cliente) terá que armazenar esse valor internamente de alguma maneira, então o limite está mais associado a como cada navegador foi desenvolvido e quais são das limitações de hardware em que está executando. É possível que cada navegador defina um limite e não seria estranho se fossem limites distintos.”*

Comment: Apenas comentando, era esperado que as especificações não definissem isso porque é uma limitação de implementação, não de especificação. O navegador (ou qualquer cliente) terá que armazenar esse valor internamente de alguma maneira, então o limite está mais associado a como cada navegador foi desenvolvido e quais são das limitações de *hardware* em que está executando. É possível que cada navegador defina um limite e não seria estranho se fossem limites distintos.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ótimo comentário, provável que assim o seja.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss realmente -- vou colocar um quote do seu comentário na resposta achei ele muito importante para a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

O valor padrão é de **524288 caracteres**. O qual na minha opinião é uma escolha que **limita a implementação**, pois o valor poderia ser armazenado em algum local como o `storage` ou **banco de dados**, porém este valor é uma escolha para limitar a entrada de **512 KB**.

Atualmente este valor de **KB** é dependente do determinado navegador, como por exemplo: 
Os desenvolvedores do **Chrome** encontraram um problema de desempenho com textos mais longo do que isso e então eles apertaram o `maxLength` e, aparentemente, eles se esqueceram disso depois.